# Duplicate attribute class causing site validation error

Tags: css, validation, post-class

The following bit of code results in a duplicate attribute site validation error.

This template script:

```
<div class="clearfix" <?php post_class() ?>>
```

produces this source output:

```
<div class="clearfix" class="post-263 post type-post status-publish format-st…
```

WordPress adds its own post-related classes to format the blog entry. Is there any way I can add my "clearfix" class to the template without producing the duplicate attributes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
<div <?php post_class("clearfix"); ?>>
```

See [post_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) for more details

Comment: Your welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as answered if this is the correct answer.